# Accessing Nested Dictionaries-Student Data

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Below is the code I have tried, actually I am looking for result like comparision of each key dictionary so my max_value for each dictionary will be like "2539:Mark:35" … same thing for rest other dictionary pls help me here to solve this..

```py
student_data = {2539:{'James':30, 'Mark': 35}, 8214: { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40},7411:{'Travis':28, 'Mark': 45}}

for id,v in student_data.items():
    print(id, '-->', student_data[id][0] + ',', max(student_data[id][1].values()))
    print('Subjects:', student_data[id][2], '\n')
```

Comment: the dictionary seems incomplete

Comment: student_data = { 2539: { 'James':    30, 'Mark': 35 },
                     8214: { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40    },
                     7411: { 'Travis':   28, 'Mark': 45  }  }

Comment: what will be ur output?

Comment: Output will be like 2539:Mark:35 and so on for other keys also here the maximum value is for mark which is 35, so the max function checks between the values of James and Mark to have maximum

Comment: Please add expected output to your post and show it as full python code.

Comment: Actually now I am looking for output like below....taking user input as student ID
Enter Student ID: 2539

Output:
Mark:35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as much as possible.

Use [find max in dictionary](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-max-value-in-a-dictionary-in-python) to find key with max value in dictionary

**Code**

```
student_data = { 2539: { 'James': 30, 'Mark': 35 }, 8214: { 'Michelle': 32,'Mark': 40 }, 7411: { 'Travis': 28, 'Mark': 45 } }

for id,v in student_data.items():       # v is a dictionary
    max_student = max(v, key=v.get)     # student name with max
    print(f'{id}:{max_student}:{v[max_student]}')
```

**Output**

```
2539:Mark:35
8214:Mark:40
7411:Mark:45
```

**Expanded to input info for student_data**

```
def get_parameter(prompt, type_input='str'):
  " Used for getting student id, name or score "
  while True:
    param = input(prompt)
    if not param:
      return None # done entering

    if type_input=='int':
      if param.isdigit():
        return int(param)
      else:
        print('Value should be integer')
    elif type_input == 'str':
      if param.isalpha():
        # string so okay
        return param
      else:
        print('Value should be single word string')

# Get student data as list of stuples
# [(id1, name1, score1), (id2, name2, score2), ...]
while True:
    id = get_parameter('Student id (blank line to close entries):', 'int')
    if not id:
        break  # break inputting data on blank line

    name = get_parameter('Student name: ')
    if not name:
      break

    score = get_parameter('Student score: ', 'int')
    if not score:
      break

    data.append((id, name, score))

# Convert list of tuples to student_data dictionary
student_data = {}
for id, name, score in data:
    if not id in student_data:
        student_data[id] = {}  # add dictionary for id
    # Add score and name
    student_data[id][name] = score

# Show results    
for id,v in student_data.items():
    max_student = max(v, key=v.get )
    print(f'{id}:{max_student}:{v[max_student]}')
```

Comment: Got it works perfectly... But if I need an user input for example... I take user input like Enter Student ID: 2539 and the result show us like Mark:35 and same for ID's also.. pls help if you can

Comment: @SyedFarhanAhmed--Sorry for the delay, just saw your post a few minutes ago.  I updated my answer to include input data.  Is this what you meant?